# Wifi not connecting automatically on boot

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I have finally got the Broadcom wifi network card to work--`Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)`. This [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) was very helpful. However, every time I boot the computer, I have to go into terminal and enter the following commands in order to get the wifi working:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl
sudo modprobe wl
```

How can I connect to the wifi automatically when I boot my computer without having to manually enter the commands above manually every time I boot?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean wifi network card, not router? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Yes, I mean the wifi network card. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

You have this problem, because you installed b43 driver.

It can be fixed by

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This package will blacklist b43 permanently.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I entered the command you suggested in Terminal, but after reboot still the same issue. I have to manually enter the two command lines above in order to get the wifi to work.

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf` to your question.

Comment: output: cat: /etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-sta-common.conf No such file or directory

Comment: What `ls /etc/modprobe.d` shows?

Comment: It shows:
/etc/modprobe.d: Is a directory